# Deploy SQL Express in App_Data directory

Tags: asp.net, wcf, deployment, sql-server-express, appdata

Despite using many sql databases before, I've never actually tried to develop an app with a database in the App_Data directory.

Until now!!

It's a small WCF service project, which has a sql express 2008 r2 database.

Working in VS there are no problems, I thought it would be as easy as deploying to a server (win 2008 with sql 2008 r2 installed) and it would just work.  But it would appear not.

In the web.config, the connection string which uses |Data Directory| in the connection string.

I read [here](http://goo.gl/fuFi) that |Data Directory| only works in VS, but looking at other articles on the web that doesn't seem to be the case.

I have (for the sake of this) given everyone modify rights on the app_data dir on the server.

I deployed using the package feature in VS 2010.

Thx
S

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"?  Is there any error be throwing?

Comment: The error being thrown is from WCF, its a connection refused exception(i think...im at home now, trying to remember).  But other methods on the service that dont use sql are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was related to the application pool account in IIS not having permissions on the SQL Express instance.

Comment: @SteveCI, can you please provide some more info?